# Why does this React/Mobx observer component not rerender when its observable props change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, mobx-react

I have a React component which renders a table of data from its props. The data is wrapped in MobX's `observable()`. From time to time, an asynchronous operation (AJAX call) adds a new row to the data source, which should cause a new table row to render. This is not the case.

A minimal example of the component in question is below:

```
@observer
class MyDashboard extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Table
                columns={this.props.columns}
                dataSource={this.props.model.contentTypes}
            />
        );
    }

    @action.bound
    private onThingHappened = async () => {
        const thing = await asyncThing();
        runInAction('onThingHappened', () => {
            this.props.model.contentTypes.push(thing);
        });
    }
}
```

The prop `model` is an observable object. `model.contentTypes` is an array of objects. The table renders correctly on the first draw; it's subsequent re-renders which are problematic.

The bound action `onThingHappened` works as expected if the `await` is removed. To put it differently - model changes which occur before the first `await` trigger re-renders as expected.

The `runInAction` does not seem to noticably change anything.

However, if I draw `model.contentTypes` in the component itself - rather than simply passing it down to a child component (`<Table>` in this case), the entire thing works as expected. For example:

```
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div style={{display: 'none'}}>{this.props.model.contentTypes.length}</div>
            <Table
                columns={this.props.columns}
                dataSource={this.props.model.contentTypes}
            />
        </React.Fragment>
    )
```

In this render function, dereferencing the `model.contentTypes` array seems to be enough to trigger the re-render in `onThingHappened`, even after an `await`.

Comment: I've also wrapped `Table` in `observer()` in hopes that it would pay better attention, but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use mobx but after some research:

- wrapping `<Table/>` in `observer()` should work ... if `<Table/>` render uses the value directly, it can fail if passed to (unwrapped) subcomponent;

*'Mobx traces access'* then probably it's enough to force mobx to react by 'unnecessary' access.

Try sth like:

```
render() {
  const amount = this.props.model.contentTypes.length;
  if( !amount ) return null; // to avoid 'amount unused, no unused ...'

  return (
    <Table
      columns={this.props.columns}
      dataSource={this.props.model.contentTypes}
    />
  );
}
```